# Node-red flow modifications

Tags: node-red

Can anyone help me modify the start/stop button so that it has the same feature as the Emergency Stop button features?

But instead of 'current/total downtime', it has 'current/total cycletime'. So the dashboard for the start/stop button should have:-

1. Start/stop pressed at
2. Start/stop released at
3. Current CycleTime
4. Total CycleTime

I tried when pressing the start/stop button, it does not generate a time, and when i press the emergency it doesn't turn off the Start/stop button.

```
[{"id":"f2ed81a2e52736e0","type":"group","z":"1e58afab75a2237b","style":{"stroke":"#999999","stroke-opacity":"1","fill":"none","fill-opacity":"1","label":true,"label-position":"nw","color":"#a4a4a4"},"nodes":["1db41e0a238e5459","b20484b6cd96afd7","b5608a0938cc8ed2","005d1219638fe0b2","e56f4e4623897090","086a245709e9252e","2dc2ec9a8361bdc3","9f16ba55089506b6","c197dc32a12028c9","48a27b6336c12807","e9b12dea270e6fcf","8849ee1c3cf7747b","e6a30c3008ff87be","d72a77e002b9b61a","fdf9d1a8a2ecfead","9a20ba6502c0c805","0eaf8fa2cc718ad8","30e1a6ed8568de4f"],"x":234,"y":1459,"w":932,"h":502},{"id":"1db41e0a238e5459","type":"comment","z":"1e58afab75a2237b","g":"f2ed81a2e52736e0","name":"Emergency Stop","info":"","x":340,"y":1700,"wires":[]},{"id":"b20484b6cd96afd7","type":"function","z":"1e58afab75a2237b","g":"f2ed81a2e52736e0","name":"function 108","func":"var onoff = msg.payload\nvar nd = new Date()     //Date in Object Format\nvar dt = nd.toString()  //Convert to String format\nvar src = \"emg_stop\"\nvar ts = nd.getTime()\ndt = nd.toLocaleString(\"ta-LK\")\n\nmsg.payload = {\n    di : onoff,\n    dt : dt,\n    source : src,\n    timestamp : ts \n}\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"initialize":"","finalize":"","libs":[],"x":770,"y":1740,"wires":[["b5608a0938cc8ed2"]]},{"id":"b5608a0938cc8ed2","type":"mqtt out","z":"1e58afab75a2237b","g":"f2ed81a2e52736e0","name":"","topic":"oee/line1","qos":"","retain":"","respTopic":"","contentType":"","userProps":"","correl":"","expiry":"","broker":"ca97eb64ab19c683","x":1000,"y":1740,"wires":[]},{"id":"005d1219638fe0b2","type":"function","z":"1e58afab75a2237b","g":"f2ed81a2e52736e0","name":"Reset Function","func":"var source = \"reset\"\nmsg.payload=\n{\n    source:source\n}\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"initialize":"","finalize":"","libs":[],"x":900,"y":1920,"wires":[["086a245709e9252e"]]},{"id":"e56f4e4623897090","type":"ui_button","z":"1e58afab75a2237b","g":"f2ed81a2e52736e0","name":"","group":"6b288869ce54b0c5","order":5,"width":0,"height":0,"passthru":false,"label":"Reset Button","tooltip":"","color":"","bgcolor":"","className":"","icon":"mi-refresh","payload":"","payloadType":"str","topic":"topic","topicType":"msg","x":330,"y":1920,"wires":[["005d1219638fe0b2"]]},{"id":"086a245709e9252e","type":"mqtt out","z":"1e58afab75a2237b","g":"f2ed81a2e52736e0","name":"","topic":"oee/line1","qos":"","retain":"","respTopic":"","contentType":"","userProps":"","correl":"","expiry":"","broker":"ca97eb64ab19c683","x":1080,"y":1920,"wires":[]},{"id":"2dc2ec9a8361bdc3","type":"change","z":"1e58afab75a2237b","g":"f2ed81a2e52736e0","name":"","rules":[{"t":"change","p":"payload","pt":"msg","from":"true","fromt":"bool","to":"0","tot":"str"},{"t":"change","p":"payload","pt":"msg","from":"false","fromt":"bool","to":"1","tot":"str"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":560,"y":1740,"wires":[["b20484b6cd96afd7"]]},{"id":"9f16ba55089506b6","type":"ui_switch","z":"1e58afab75a2237b","g":"f2ed81a2e52736e0","name":"","label":"Emergency Stop","tooltip":"","group":"6b288869ce54b0c5","order":2,"width":0,"height":0,"passthru":true,"decouple":"false","topic":"topic","topicType":"msg","style":"","onvalue":"true","onvalueType":"bool","onicon":"","oncolor":"","offvalue":"false","offvalueType":"bool","officon":"","offcolor":"","animate":false,"className":"","x":350,"y":1820,"wires":[["48a27b6336c12807","0eaf8fa2cc718ad8"]]},{"id":"c197dc32a12028c9","type":"comment","z":"1e58afab75a2237b","g":"f2ed81a2e52736e0","name":"Reset","info":"","x":310,"y":1880,"wires":[]},{"id":"48a27b6336c12807","type":"change","z":"1e58afab75a2237b","g":"f2ed81a2e52736e0","name":"","rules":[{"t":"change","p":"payload","pt":"msg","from":"true","fromt":"bool","to":"1","tot":"str"},{"t":"change","p":"payload","pt":"msg","from":"false","fromt":"bool","to":"0","tot":"str"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":580,"y":1800,"wires":[["b20484b6cd96afd7"]]},{"id":"e9b12dea270e6fcf","type":"comment","z":"1e58afab75a2237b","g":"f2ed81a2e52736e0","name":"Start/Stop","info":"","x":320,"y":1500,"wires":[]},{"id":"8849ee1c3cf7747b","type":"function","z":"1e58afab75a2237b","g":"f2ed81a2e52736e0","name":"function 108","func":"var onoff = msg.payload\nvar nd = new Date()     //Date in Object Format\nvar dt = nd.toString()  //Convert to String format\nvar src = \"start_stop\"\nvar ts = nd.getTime()\ndt = nd.toLocaleString(\"ta-LK\")\n\nmsg.payload = {\n    di : onoff,\n    dt : dt,\n    source : src,\n    timestamp : ts \n}\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"initialize":"","finalize":"","libs":[],"x":750,"y":1540,"wires":[["e6a30c3008ff87be"]]},{"id":"e6a30c3008ff87be","type":"mqtt out","z":"1e58afab75a2237b","g":"f2ed81a2e52736e0","name":"","topic":"oee/line1","qos":"","retain":"","respTopic":"","contentType":"","userProps":"","correl":"","expiry":"","broker":"ca97eb64ab19c683","x":980,"y":1540,"wires":[]},{"id":"d72a77e002b9b61a","type":"change","z":"1e58afab75a2237b","g":"f2ed81a2e52736e0","name":"","rules":[{"t":"change","p":"payload","pt":"msg","from":"true","fromt":"bool","to":"0","tot":"str"},{"t":"change","p":"payload","pt":"msg","from":"false","fromt":"bool","to":"1","tot":"str"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":540,"y":1540,"wires":[["8849ee1c3cf7747b"]]},{"id":"fdf9d1a8a2ecfead","type":"ui_switch","z":"1e58afab75a2237b","g":"f2ed81a2e52736e0","name":"","label":"Start/Stop","tooltip":"","group":"6b288869ce54b0c5","order":4,"width":0,"height":0,"passthru":true,"decouple":"false","topic":"topic","topicType":"msg","style":"","onvalue":"true","onvalueType":"bool","onicon":"","oncolor":"","offvalue":"false","offvalueType":"bool","officon":"","offcolor":"","animate":false,"className":"","x":330,"y":1620,"wires":[["9a20ba6502c0c805","30e1a6ed8568de4f"]]},{"id":"9a20ba6502c0c805","type":"change","z":"1e58afab75a2237b","g":"f2ed81a2e52736e0","name":"","rules":[{"t":"change","p":"payload","pt":"msg","from":"true","fromt":"bool","to":"0","tot":"str"},{"t":"change","p":"payload","pt":"msg","from":"false","fromt":"bool","to":"1","tot":"str"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":560,"y":1600,"wires":[["8849ee1c3cf7747b"]]},{"id":"0eaf8fa2cc718ad8","type":"ui_led","z":"1e58afab75a2237b","g":"f2ed81a2e52736e0","order":1,"group":"6b288869ce54b0c5","width":0,"height":0,"label":"Emergency LED","labelPlacement":"left","labelAlignment":"left","colorForValue":[{"color":"#00ff00","value":"true","valueType":"bool"},{"color":"#ff0000","value":"true","valueType":"bool"}],"allowColorForValueInMessage":false,"shape":"circle","showGlow":true,"name":"","x":590,"y":1860,"wires":[]},{"id":"30e1a6ed8568de4f","type":"ui_led","z":"1e58afab75a2237b","g":"f2ed81a2e52736e0","order":3,"group":"6b288869ce54b0c5","width":0,"height":0,"label":"Start/Stop LED","labelPlacement":"left","labelAlignment":"left","colorForValue":[{"color":"#00ff00","value":"true","valueType":"bool"},{"color":"#ff0000","value":"true","valueType":"bool"}],"allowColorForValueInMessage":false,"shape":"circle","showGlow":true,"name":"","x":550,"y":1660,"wires":[]},{"id":"ca97eb64ab19c683","type":"mqtt-broker","name":"","broker":"broker.hivemq.com","port":"1883","clientid":"","autoConnect":true,"usetls":false,"protocolVersion":"4","keepalive":"60","cleansession":true,"birthTopic":"","birthQos":"0","birthPayload":"","birthMsg":{},"closeTopic":"","closeQos":"0","closePayload":"","closeMsg":{},"willTopic":"","willQos":"0","willPayload":"","willMsg":{},"userProps":"","sessionExpiry":""},{"id":"6b288869ce54b0c5","type":"ui_group","name":"Buttons Dashboard","tab":"73d9a4f493c31f3c","order":2,"disp":true,"width":10,"collapse":false,"className":""},{"id":"73d9a4f493c31f3c","type":"ui_tab","name":"Weighing RS232","icon":"dashboard","order":1,"disabled":false,"hidden":false},{"id":"c8d46037427f639b","type":"group","z":"1e58afab75a2237b","style":{"stroke":"#999999","stroke-opacity":"1","fill":"none","fill-opacity":"1","label":true,"label-position":"nw","color":"#a4a4a4"},"nodes":["9d5e0f6388cda5f3","3ec963e398a24438","c1977a02048afc70","61ae03e0c8ba938e","309d1a7400c9ae97","84e08ad198d6ad3c","44f67cc51cf44993","7295f23b8007eb88","95af98f5fe639bbc","089b8731c3cd787e","5e540149fed8e3a6","cbd7c5d66fe14eb7","27ed3b0734350708","fbd10cb095bcd2b8","bb03373147fb1a91","571ffdc492b54b9f","654880e8de33bfbd","922d37a222e0f0c9","62b69b7ca2c2c03b","9e0996f4c8cc2eb4","78b7fd7367ea4224","fd9c82812a3bf6fc","193d79dcf7275ad9","fc6b82eca0217c2b","3b80a73d1f9e82cb","a357c64da5e8e196","33c29d0210cae3c7","643a9849c5786dba"],"x":234,"y":2019,"w":1512,"h":622},{"id":"9d5e0f6388cda5f3","type":"mqtt in","z":"1e58afab75a2237b","g":"c8d46037427f639b","name":"","topic":"oee/line1","qos":"2","datatype":"auto-detect","broker":"ca97eb64ab19c683","nl":false,"rap":true,"rh":0,"inputs":0,"x":320,"y":2160,"wires":[["089b8731c3cd787e"]]},{"id":"3ec963e398a24438","type":"ui_text","z":"1e58afab75a2237b","g":"c8d46037427f639b","group":"ca4c960b366919f0","order":2,"width":7,"height":1,"name":"","label":"Emg Pressed at","format":"{{msg.payload.dt}}","layout":"row-spread","className":"","style":false,"font":"","fontSize":"","color":"#000000","x":920,"y":2320,"wires":[]},{"id":"c1977a02048afc70","type":"ui_text","z":"1e58afab75a2237b","g":"c8d46037427f639b","group":"ca4c960b366919f0","order":3,"width":7,"height":1,"name":"","label":"Emg Released at","format":"{{msg.payload.dt}}","layout":"row-spread","className":"","style":false,"font":"","fontSize":"","color":"#000000","x":930,"y":2280,"wires":[]},{"id":"61ae03e0c8ba938e","type":"switch","z":"1e58afab75a2237b","g":"c8d46037427f639b","name":"di/Emergency","property":"payload.di","propertyType":"msg","rules":[{"t":"eq","v":"1","vt":"str"},{"t":"eq","v":"0","vt":"str"}],"checkall":"true","repair":false,"outputs":2,"x":660,"y":2360,"wires":[["3ec963e398a24438","84e08ad198d6ad3c"],["c1977a02048afc70","44f67cc51cf44993"]]},{"id":"309d1a7400c9ae97","type":"comment","z":"1e58afab75a2237b","g":"c8d46037427f639b","name":"Downtime","info":"","x":1260,"y":2460,"wires":[]},{"id":"84e08ad198d6ad3c","type":"function","z":"1e58afab75a2237b","g":"c8d46037427f639b","name":"generate TS when red is ON","func":"var nd = new Date()\nvar ts = nd.getTime()\nvar hts = nd.toLocaleString(\"sv-SE\")\nflow.set(\"EMGON\",ts)\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"initialize":"","finalize":"","libs":[],"x":1000,"y":2400,"wires":[["7295f23b8007eb88"]]},{"id":"44f67cc51cf44993","type":"function","z":"1e58afab75a2237b","g":"c8d46037427f639b","name":"generate TS when red is OFF","func":"var nd = new Date()\nvar ts = nd.getTime()\nvar hts = nd.toLocaleString(\"sv-SE\")\nflow.set(\"EMGOFF\", ts)\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"initialize":"","finalize":"","libs":[],"x":1010,"y":2440,"wires":[["7295f23b8007eb88"]]},{"id":"7295f23b8007eb88","type":"function","z":"1e58afab75a2237b","g":"c8d46037427f639b","name":"Calculate Downtime","func":"var downtime\ndowntime = flow.get(\"EMGOFF\") - flow.get(\"EMGON\")\ndowntime = downtime/1000\ndowntime = downtime.toFixed(2)\ndowntime = Number(downtime)\nflow.set(\"Downtime\",downtime)\n\nif ( downtime >= 0 )\n{\n    var totaldowntime = flow.get(\"totaldowntime\") || 0\n    totaldowntime = totaldowntime + downtime\n    totaldowntime = Number(totaldowntime.toFixed(2))\n    flow.set(\"totaldowntime\", totaldowntime)\n}\n\nmsg.payload = \n{\n    downtime : downtime ,\n    totaldowntime : totaldowntime\n}\n//2nd method for round off 2 decimal\n//Math.floor :2.97 ->2\n//Math.ceil :2.97 ->3\n//Math.round : 2.97 ->3\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"initialize":"","finalize":"","libs":[],"x":1300,"y":2420,"wires":[["95af98f5fe639bbc","33c29d0210cae3c7"]]},{"id":"95af98f5fe639bbc","type":"ui_text","z":"1e58afab75a2237b","g":"c8d46037427f639b","group":"ca4c960b366919f0","order":4,"width":7,"height":1,"name":"","label":"Current Downtime","format":"{{msg.payload.downtime}} secs","layout":"row-spread","className":"","style":false,"font":"","fontSize":"","color":"#000000","x":1610,"y":2280,"wires":[]},{"id":"089b8731c3cd787e","type":"switch","z":"1e58afab75a2237b","g":"c8d46037427f639b","name":"source","property":"payload.source","propertyType":"msg","rules":[{"t":"eq","v":"sensor_1","vt":"str"},{"t":"eq","v":"inductive","vt":"str"},{"t":"eq","v":"sensor_3","vt":"str"},{"t":"eq","v":"emg_stop","vt":"str"},{"t":"eq","v":"reset","vt":"str"}],"checkall":"true","repair":false,"outputs":5,"x":490,"y":2160,"wires":[["571ffdc492b54b9f"],["654880e8de33bfbd"],["922d37a222e0f0c9"],["61ae03e0c8ba938e"],["193d79dcf7275ad9"]]},{"id":"5e540149fed8e3a6","type":"debug","z":"1e58afab75a2237b","g":"c8d46037427f639b","name":"debug 65","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":true,"complete":"payload","targetType":"msg","statusVal":"payload","statusType":"auto","x":1620,"y":2060,"wires":[]},{"id":"cbd7c5d66fe14eb7","type":"function","z":"1e58afab75a2237b","g":"c8d46037427f639b","name":"generate TS when sensor 1 is On","func":"var fullone= flow.get(\"currentruntime\")\nvar nd = new Date()\nvar ts = nd.getTime()\nvar hts = nd.toLocaleString(\"sv-SE\")\nif (flow.get(\"fullcycle\") == 1) \n{\n fullone = flow.get(\"sensor3\")-flow.get(\"sensor1\")\n flow.set(\"currentruntime\", fullone)\n flow.set(\"fullcycle\",0)\n}\nflow.set(\"sensor1\", ts)\nflow.set(\"halfcycle\",1)\n\nmsg.payload = \n{\n    fullone:fullone\n}\n\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"initialize":"","finalize":"","libs":[],"x":1060,"y":2080,"wires":[[]]},{"id":"27ed3b0734350708","type":"function","z":"1e58afab75a2237b","g":"c8d46037427f639b","name":"Detect Wood = 1","func":"flow.set(\"metal\", 1)\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"initialize":"","finalize":"","libs":[],"x":750,"y":2560,"wires":[[]]},{"id":"fbd10cb095bcd2b8","type":"function","z":"1e58afab75a2237b","g":"c8d46037427f639b","name":"generate TS when sensor 3 is On","func":"var nd = new Date()\nvar ts = nd.getTime()\nvar hts = nd.toLocaleString(\"sv-SE\")\nflow.set(\"sensor3\", ts)\n\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"initialize":"","finalize":"","libs":[],"x":1060,"y":2120,"wires":[["bb03373147fb1a91"]]},{"id":"bb03373147fb1a91","type":"function","z":"1e58afab75a2237b","g":"c8d46037427f639b","name":"Calculate Cycletime/Runtime","func":"var runtime\nruntime = flow.get(\"sensor3\") - flow.get(\"sensor1\")\nruntime = runtime/1000\nruntime = runtime.toFixed(2)\nruntime = Number(runtime)\nflow.set(\"RUNTIME\", runtime)\n\nmsg.payload =\n{\n    runtime:runtime ,   \n}\n\n//2nd method for round off 2 decimal\n//Math.floor :2.97 ->2\n//Math.ceil :2.97 ->3\n//Math.round : 2.97 ->3\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"initialize":"","finalize":"","libs":[],"x":1400,"y":2100,"wires":[["5e540149fed8e3a6","9e0996f4c8cc2eb4"]]},{"id":"571ffdc492b54b9f","type":"switch","z":"1e58afab75a2237b","g":"c8d46037427f639b","name":"di/Sensor 1","property":"payload.di","propertyType":"msg","rules":[{"t":"eq","v":"1","vt":"str"},{"t":"eq","v":"0","vt":"str"}],"checkall":"true","repair":false,"outputs":2,"x":690,"y":2060,"wires":[["cbd7c5d66fe14eb7"],[]]},{"id":"654880e8de33bfbd","type":"switch","z":"1e58afab75a2237b","g":"c8d46037427f639b","name":"di/Inductive","property":"payload.di","propertyType":"msg","rules":[{"t":"eq","v":"1","vt":"str"},{"t":"eq","v":"0","vt":"str"}],"checkall":"true","repair":false,"outputs":2,"x":470,"y":2560,"wires":[["27ed3b0734350708"],[]]},{"id":"922d37a222e0f0c9","type":"switch","z":"1e58afab75a2237b","g":"c8d46037427f639b","name":"di/Sensor 3","property":"payload.di","propertyType":"msg","rules":[{"t":"eq","v":"1","vt":"str"},{"t":"eq","v":"0","vt":"str"}],"checkall":"true","repair":false,"outputs":2,"x":690,"y":2140,"wires":[["fbd10cb095bcd2b8","78b7fd7367ea4224"],[]]},{"id":"62b69b7ca2c2c03b","type":"comment","z":"1e58afab75a2237b","g":"c8d46037427f639b","name":"Runtime","info":"","x":1360,"y":2060,"wires":[]},{"id":"9e0996f4c8cc2eb4","type":"ui_text","z":"1e58afab75a2237b","g":"c8d46037427f639b","group":"ca4c960b366919f0","order":1,"width":14,"height":1,"name":"","label":"Actual Cycle Time","format":"{{msg.payload.runtime}} secs","layout":"row-spread","className":"","style":false,"font":"","fontSize":"","color":"#000000","x":1630,"y":2160,"wires":[]},{"id":"78b7fd7367ea4224","type":"function","z":"1e58afab75a2237b","g":"c8d46037427f639b","name":"Detect Wood = 0 // All Count","func":"var metal = flow.get(\"metal\")\nvar ngcnt = flow.get(\"ngcnt\") || 0\nvar goodpart = flow.get(\"goodpart\") || 0\nvar siggnal\n\nif (metal  == 1 )\n{\n    siggnal = \"NG\"\n    ngcnt = ngcnt + 1\n    flow.set(\"ngcnt\", ngcnt)\n    msg.statusdisplay = '<font color=\"#FA8072\">NG</font'\n    \n}\nelse if (metal == 0) \n{\n    siggnal = \"OK\"\n    msg.statusdisplay = '<font color=\"Green\">OK</font'\n    goodpart = goodpart + 1\n    flow.set(\"goodpart\", goodpart)\n}\n\nvar partid\nvar totalcount = flow.get(\"goodpart\") + flow.get(\"ngcnt\")\npartid = totalcount + 2001\nflow.set(\"totalcount\", totalcount)\n\nvar quality = (goodpart / totalcount) * 100\nquality = Number(quality.toFixed(2))\nflow.set(\"quality\", quality)\nflow.set(\"metal\", 0)\nmsg.payload =  \n{\n    siggnal:siggnal,\n    ngcnt:ngcnt,\n    goodpart: goodpart,\n    quality: quality,\n    partid: partid,\n    totalcount: totalcount\n}\n     \n \n\n\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"initialize":"","finalize":"","libs":[],"x":1040,"y":2160,"wires":[[]]},{"id":"fd9c82812a3bf6fc","type":"function","z":"1e58afab75a2237b","g":"c8d46037427f639b","name":"NG/Good Counter","func":"var partid\nvar totalcount = flow.get(\"totalcount\") || 0\ntotalcount = totalcount + 1\npartid = totalcount + 2001\n\nvar ngcounter = flow.get(\"ngcnt\")\nvar goodpart = totalcount - ngcounter\nflow.set(\"totalcount\", totalcount)\n\nvar quality = (goodpart/totalcount)*100\nquality = Number(quality.toFixed(2))\nflow.set(\"quality\",quality)\nmsg.payload =\n{\n    ngcounter : ngcounter ,\n    goodpart  : goodpart ,\n    quality : quality ,\n    partid : partid ,\n    totalcount : totalcount\n}\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"initialize":"","finalize":"","libs":[],"x":1150,"y":2320,"wires":[[]]},{"id":"193d79dcf7275ad9","type":"function","z":"1e58afab75a2237b","g":"c8d46037427f639b","name":"Reset Function","func":"flow.set(\"RUNTIME\",0)\nflow.set(\"EMGON\", 0)\nflow.set(\"EMGOFF\", 0)\nflow.set(\"metal\",0)\nflow.set(\"ngcnt\",0)\nflow.set(\"sensor1\",0)\nflow.set(\"sensor3\",0)\nflow.set(\"totalcount\",0)\nflow.set(\"totaldowntime\",0)\nflow.set(\"avai\", 0)\nflow.set(\"performance\", 0)\nflow.set(\"quality\", 0)\nflow.set(\"goodpart\",0)\nmsg.payload =\n{\n    dt:0,\n    runtime:0,\n    totalcount:0,\n    ngcnt:0,\n    goodpart:0,\n    downtime:0,\n    totaldowntime:0,\n    avai:0,\n    perf:0,\n    quality:0,\n    setmetal:0,\n    partid:2001,\n}\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"initialize":"","finalize":"","libs":[],"x":480,"y":2600,"wires":[["fc6b82eca0217c2b"]]},{"id":"fc6b82eca0217c2b","type":"link out","z":"1e58afab75a2237b","g":"c8d46037427f639b","name":"Reset Link","mode":"link","links":["3b80a73d1f9e82cb","a357c64da5e8e196","dadc6a5a04370d2d"],"x":675,"y":2600,"wires":[]},{"id":"3b80a73d1f9e82cb","type":"link in","z":"1e58afab75a2237b","g":"c8d46037427f639b","name":"link in 7","links":["fc6b82eca0217c2b"],"x":1225,"y":2180,"wires":[["9e0996f4c8cc2eb4","95af98f5fe639bbc","33c29d0210cae3c7"]]},{"id":"a357c64da5e8e196","type":"link in","z":"1e58afab75a2237b","g":"c8d46037427f639b","name":"link in 8","links":["fc6b82eca0217c2b"],"x":765,"y":2200,"wires":[["3ec963e398a24438","c1977a02048afc70"]]},{"id":"33c29d0210cae3c7","type":"ui_text","z":"1e58afab75a2237b","g":"c8d46037427f639b","group":"ca4c960b366919f0","order":5,"width":7,"height":1,"name":"","label":"Total Downtime","format":"{{msg.payload.totaldowntime}}sec","layout":"row-spread","className":"","style":false,"font":"","fontSize":"","color":"#000000","x":1600,"y":2320,"wires":[]},{"id":"643a9849c5786dba","type":"function","z":"1e58afab75a2237b","g":"c8d46037427f639b","name":"Detect Wood = 0 // All Count","func":"var metal = flow.get(\"metal\")\nvar ngcnt = flow.get(\"ngcnt\") || 0\nvar siggnal\n\nif (metal  == 1 )\n{\n    siggnal = \"NG\"\n    ngcnt = ngcnt + 1\n    flow.set(\"ngcnt\", ngcnt)\n    msg.statusdisplay = '<font color=\"#FA8072\">NG</font'\n    flow.set(\"metal\", 0)\n}\nelse if (metal == 0) \n{\n    siggnal = \"OK\"\n    msg.statusdisplay = '<font color=\"Green\">OK</font'\n}\n\nvar partid\nvar totalcount = flow.get(\"totalcount\") || 0\nvar goodpart\ntotalcount = totalcount + 1\ngoodpart = totalcount - ngcnt\nflow.set(\"totalcount\", totalcount)\npartid = totalcount + 2001\n\nvar quality = (goodpart / totalcount) * 100\nquality = Number(quality.toFixed(2))\nflow.set(\"quality\", quality)\nmsg.payload =  \n{\n    siggnal:siggnal,\n    ngcnt:ngcnt,\n    goodpart: goodpart,\n    quality: quality,\n    partid: partid,\n    totalcount: totalcount\n}\n     \n \n\n\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"initialize":"","finalize":"","libs":[],"x":1080,"y":2580,"wires":[[]]},{"id":"ca4c960b366919f0","type":"ui_group","name":"Table of Data","tab":"73d9a4f493c31f3c","order":3,"disp":true,"width":14,"collapse":false,"className":""}]
```